# Convert from Direct3D11CaptureFrame to OpenCV's cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, directx, directx-11, capture

I'm trying to convert from a `Direct3D11CaptureFrame`, obtained as in the example from [Microsoft's Screen Capture documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture) (and verified to be correct by saving it on disk), to a cv::Mat. I am converting the frame's surface into a `ID3D11Texture2D` in the following way, and it seems to work:

```cpp
void processFrame(const winrt::Windows::Graphics::Capture::Direct3D11CaptureFrame &frame) {
       winrt::com_ptr<Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11::IDirect3DDxgiInterfaceAccess> access =
          frame.Surface().as<Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11::IDirect3DDxgiInterfaceAccess>();
      winrt::com_ptr<ID3D11Texture2D> frameSurface;
      winrt::check_hresult(access->GetInterface(winrt::guid_of<ID3D11Texture2D>(), frameSurface.put_void()));
      (...)
}
```

From this point, looking at [opencv's d3d interop samples](https://github.com/dalieu/opencv/blob/master/samples/directx/d3d11_interop.cpp), I see I have two options. The first one consists in using `cv::directx::convertFromD3D11Texture2D` such as

```cpp
void processFrame(const winrt::Windows::Graphics::Capture::Direct3D11CaptureFrame &frame) {
       winrt::com_ptr<Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11::IDirect3DDxgiInterfaceAccess> access =
          frame.Surface().as<Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11::IDirect3DDxgiInterfaceAccess>();
      winrt::com_ptr<ID3D11Texture2D> frameSurface;
      winrt::check_hresult(access->GetInterface(winrt::guid_of<ID3D11Texture2D>(), frameSurface.put_void()));

  cv::Mat img;
  // throws exception in the following line
  //
  cv::directx::convertFromD3D11Texture2D(frameSurface.get(), img);
}
```

But it throws an exception after calling the destructor of the input array (`frameSurface.get()`). This method is used for GPU work in the code examples, but I haven't  seen it stated as exclusively for GPU in [the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/de/dc1/group__core__directx.html#gaaea63f9b492b4a84e1e9ef6d4eba377c).

The second option goes through a couple more hoops:

```cpp
void processFrame(const winrt::Windows::Graphics::Capture::Direct3D11CaptureFrame &frame, int height, int width) {
  auto access =
      frame.Surface().as<Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11::IDirect3DDxgiInterfaceAccess>();
  winrt::com_ptr<ID3D11Texture2D> frameSurface;
  winrt::check_hresult(
      access->GetInterface(winrt::guid_of<ID3D11Texture2D>(), frameSurface.put_void()));

  ID3D11Device *deviceD3D;
  frameSurface->GetDevice(&deviceD3D);
  ID3D11DeviceContext *m_pD3D11Ctx;
  deviceD3D->GetImmediateContext(&m_pD3D11Ctx);

  auto subResource = ::D3D11CalcSubresource(0, 0, 1);
  D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedTex;
  auto r = m_pD3D11Ctx->Map(frameSurface.get(), subResource, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mappedTex);
  // FAILS here
  //
  if (FAILED(r)) {
    throw std::runtime_error("surface mapping failed!");
  }
  cv::Mat m(height, width, CV_8UC4, mappedTex.pData, mappedTex.RowPitch);
}
```

... but it fails when mapping the context to the subresource.

I have been tweaking everything that I could think of given my inexperience with DirectX and trying to see what I am missing, but I can't find a solution for any of the two options. Does anyone see my mistakes or has a better solution for my problem?

Comment: split the problem: D3D to "bytes in main memory" + "bytes in main memory" to cv::Mat. the former _likely_ has answers and recipes. the second one certainly does (it's just one constructor call given a pointer, width, height, pixel type)

Comment: Thanks, @ChristophRackwitz. I might have to go there, but I was hoping to solve it using one of the two options above.

Answer (score 2):

1.you need new `D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC` and set: `CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ`

2.use that `D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC` to create a new `CreateTexture2D`

3.copy `frameSurface` to your new `CreateTexture2D`

```
void SimpleCapture::OnFrameArrived(
Direct3D11CaptureFramePool const& sender,
winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const&) {
    auto newSize = false;
    auto frame = sender.TryGetNextFrame();
    auto frameContentSize = frame.ContentSize();

    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
    desc.MipLevels = 1;
    desc.ArraySize = 1;
    desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    desc.SampleDesc = { 1,0 };
    desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
    desc.BindFlags = 0;
    desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
    desc.MiscFlags = 0;
    
    if (frameContentSize.Width != m_lastSize.Width ||
        frameContentSize.Height != m_lastSize.Height) {
        newSize = true;
        m_lastSize = frameContentSize;
    }
    desc.Width = m_lastSize.Width;
    desc.Height = m_lastSize.Height;

    ID3D11Texture2D* stagingTexture;
    d3dDevice.get()->CreateTexture2D(&desc, nullptr, &stagingTexture);
    
    auto frameSurface = GetDXGIInterfaceFromObject<ID3D11Texture2D>(frame.Surface());
    m_d3dContext->CopyResource(stagingTexture, frameSurface.get());

    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedTex;
    m_d3dContext->Map(stagingTexture, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &mappedTex);
    m_d3dContext->Unmap(stagingTexture, 0);

    cv::Mat c = cv::Mat(desc.Height, desc.Width, CV_8UC4, mappedTex.pData, mappedTex.RowPitch);
    cv::imshow("show", c);

    stagingTexture->Release();


    DXGI_PRESENT_PARAMETERS presentParameters = { 0 };

    if (newSize)
    {
        m_framePool.Recreate(
            m_device,
            DirectXPixelFormat::B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized,
            2,
            m_lastSize);
    }
}
```

Comment: It will work if your window will be static. But if you will change the window size, then you can get an exception on  cv::Mat c = cv::Mat(desc.Height, desc.Width....), because the window buffer size  will not fit for the new width and height. I offer to add a small checking if (!newSize){ cv::Mat = c....; cv::imshow("show", c);}.  For this case you skip creating cv::Mat  with new incorrect size  in the call of OnFrameArrived().  The next calls will pass normal. I tested that on MSVS2022 and opencv v.3.4.2 and 4.6.0